# Is there a way to install .NET Version 4.5 even if the Version .NET 4.8 is installed?

Tags: .net, .net-4.5, .net-4.8

Is there an convenient way to install .NET on my developing machine even if there is a higher .NET Version (in my case 4.8) already installed?

Comment: There's a difference between the Framework itself and SDKs or Targetting packs. The answer to the question as posed is **no**, you cannot, because all of the 4.x versions are *in-place replacements* for their previous versions. You cannot have two installed simultaneously on one machine. That's the answer *for the Framework*. Whatever you think you've installed that makes you assert "Yes", it's either a targetting pack or an SDK.

Answer (score 1):

download developer pack and it works:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net452

Answer (score -1):

Yes!

You can use this Microsoft internal link to download the Windows 8 SDK which contains the .NET Framework 4.5: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=226658

You don't need to install the full SDK because you can decide to just install the Framework in the Installation Process.